# how to turn textarea text in pdf with php

Tags: php, html-to-pdf

I have a textarea on my site that users can insert and edit text and thus has formatting and spacing. I would like for the user to push a button and generate a pdf of this textarea with the same format. I have tried allot to resolve this . Are there any good ways to do this in PHP? .

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<form action="new_pdf_test.php" method="post" name="frm1">

<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" ></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

</script>

<input type="submit" name="pdf_btn" id="pdf_btn" value="Generate PDF" />

</form>
```

when user click on "Generate PDF" button page redirect other page to generate PDF.
next page code is following.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['editor1']);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

It creating PDF but not in right way and format. Plz suggest any good way to do this.

Comment: [Use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+is%3Aquestion+title%3A%22convert+text+to+pdf%22)

Comment: This is no "plz suggest" site. Point us with your actual problem, and we'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the FPDF add-on **[HTML conversion](http://fpdf.de/Addon-53-html-conversion.html)** will help here:

> This class allows to convert HTML to PDF. It was designed to export my blog entries to PDFs.

It has a lot of features. The important ones for your situation should be:

- support for **bold**, *italics*, underlined text
- support for headlines `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` and `<h4>`
- support for images
- basic support for tables
- full support for lists `<li>`
- full support for `<blockquote>`
- support for `<br>`, `<br />` and `<p>`
- support for `<hr>` and `<hr />`

Comment: @RXSD I fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the previous answer. I agree FPDF is a great tool. However, the FPDF website can be a bit difficult to learn off - I know I had a few problems when first trying to use it!!

I have recently created a blog just to help people get their heads around the basics of FPDF as it's a bit of a different way to thinking than your usual PHP coding! If you are interested in reading it you can find it at http://www.limelightonline.co.nz/blog/create-dynamic-pdf-with-php-tutorial/

I'd be happy to help out if you have any questions or get stuck at all :D

Cheers,
Shay